# Using same variable names in files added with get_template_part()

Tags: php, templates, get-template-part

Say I have a file named `content-header.php` and `content-body.php`.

In content-header.php I have this variable:

`$some_var = 'apples';`

and in content-body.php I have a variable with the same name but different value:

`$some_var = 'bananas';`

In another file I use:

```
get_template_part('content', 'header');
get_template_part('content', 'body');
```

Would `$some_var` be limited to its own file or overwrite the other? Is it ok to use same variable names in files added through `get_template_part()`?

Would I have to use unique variable names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely use the same variable names. Arguments like that do not pass through from one template to another without a little help from a function.

So if in `content-header.php` you have `$fruit = banana;` and in `content-body.php` you have `$fruit = apple;` you will not have a conflict. Go nuts. Or bananas. ;)